# Which pre-installed apps ship with the Ubuntu 20.04 desktop installation?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, preinstallation

When we do a normal install of Ubuntu, a few pre-installed apps are included. Can anyone provide me with a list of these apps?

Answer (score 5):

The full list of installed deb-packages is available in the [manifest](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest).
The full list of applications with GUI can be obtained on the installed system with command like `dpkg -S desktop | grep "\.desktop$" | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/://' | sort -u`:

- aisleriot
- apport-gtk
- apturl-common
- at-spi2-core
- baobab
- cheese
- deja-dup
- eog
- evince
- evolution-data-server
- file-roller
- firefox
- gcr
- gdm3
- gedit
- geoclue-2.0
- gkbd-capplet
- gnome-bluetooth
- gnome-calculator
- gnome-calendar
- gnome-characters
- gnome-control-center
- gnome-disk-utility
- gnome-font-viewer
- gnome-initial-setup
- gnome-keyring
- gnome-logs
- gnome-mahjongg
- gnome-mines
- gnome-power-manager
- gnome-screenshot
- gnome-session-canberra
- gnome-settings-daemon
- gnome-shell
- gnome-startup-applications
- gnome-sudoku
- gnome-system-monitor
- gnome-terminal
- gnome-todo
- gnome-todo-common
- ibus
- ibus-table
- im-config
- info
- language-selector-gnome
- libatk-adaptoramd64:
- libcanberra-gtk3-moduleamd64:
- libreoffice-calc
- libreoffice-common
- libreoffice-draw
- libreoffice-impress
- libreoffice-math
- libreoffice-writer
- mutter
- nautilus
- network-manager-gnome
- orca
- printer-driver-foo2zjs-common
- pulseaudio
- python3.8
- remmina
- rhythmbox
- rygel
- seahorse
- shotwell
- simple-scan
- snapd
- software-properties-gtk
- speech-dispatcher
- spice-vdagent
- system-config-printer
- thunderbird
- totem
- tracker
- tracker-extract
- tracker-miner-fs
- transmission-gtk
- ubuntu-report
- ubuntu-session
- ubuntu-settings
- update-manager
- update-notifier
- usb-creator-gtk
- vim-common
- vino
- xbrlapi
- xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
- xdg-user-dirs
- xdg-user-dirs-gtk
- yelp

Comment: There was a patch, so the link doesn't work - new link:  https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest

Comment: This link is also down. But I think the new one is https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-20.04.5-desktop-amd64.manifest.

Comment: The link keeps changing. Simply open https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/, scroll down and find the current `ubuntu-20.04.X-desktop-amd64.manifest` file.